# Jquery full background gallery

Tags: jquery, background, scroll, gallery

I am not sure how can i describe what i want but as a summary i can say that i need to do something like [that](http://www.mavijeans.com.tr/#/ilovemavi) with JQuery. When i click on a picture, i will show a big version of it. Is it possible? Any plugin or sample advice?

I have found a plugin named [smoothdivscroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/index.html) but it scrolls just vertical. So it is useless for me at the moment.

Thanks for your helps

Comment: This site is to answer coding questions, not for shopping for plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help as a start point.

You just need to add an absolute layer and clone into the clicked image.

## [mouseMove gallery jsFiddle](http://jsbin.com/ifumat/2/edit)

jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
// roXon mmGallery
var mmGalSpeed = 10; // set gallery damping
var xSlider = $("#slider"); 
var posX = 0;
var sumW = 0;

$('#slider img').each(function(){
  sumW += $(this).outerWidth(true); 
  xSlider.width(sumW+3);
}); 

wDiff1 = $('#gallery_container').outerWidth(true);
wDiff2 = xSlider.width(); 
wDiff = ((wDiff2/wDiff1)-1).toFixed(2); 

mouseX = 0;
$("#gallery_container").mousemove(function(e) {
  mouseX = (e.pageX - $(this).offset().left);
});
  

setInterval(function(){ // zeno's paradox equation // "catching delay"
  posX += (mouseX - posX) / mmGalSpeed; 
  xSlider.css({left: '-'+Math.round(posX * wDiff) +'px' }); // instead 'marginLeft' use 'left' for absolute pos. #mmGallery
}, 10); 
  
});
```